# Migration to Person Account .Workflows & Process Builder

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, person-accounts

Currently we are using incorrectly a B2B model (account + contact) in a 90% B2C market. It means we are using a global account (e.g name = Europe) to link all the contacts created for Europe, the problem is clear; the model is not valid and we are facing a lot of LOCK_ERROR issues.

We are planning the migration to person accounts in order to work with both models, however there is one point no totally clear for me. What happen with all the workflows/Process builders we currently have on contact? do we have to create all of them again but in this case using account object? if that is correct, for future changes, do we have to create then always 2 workflows (on contact and on account) to apply the changes in the B2B model and also in the B2C model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of. Account Processes are triggered for Person Accounts, but not Contact Processes. That said, you can build Flows or Invocable Methods and call the same from both Processes; you'd just need to add a bit of logic upfront to determine if you're doing an Account/Person Account/Contact action and respond appropriately.